# Dropping non-constants in Algorithm Complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, complexity-theory, bellman-ford

So, basically I'm implementing an algorithm to calculate distances from one source node to every other node in a weighted graph, and if a node is in a negative cycle, it detects and marks that node as such.

My question regards the total time complexity of my algorithm. Assume `V` is number of nodes and `E` the number of edges.

The algorithm starts by asking E lines of input to specify the Edges of the graph and inserts it in the corresponding adjacency list. Such operation is `O(E)`

I apply the Bellman-Ford algorithm `V-1` times to know the distances and then I apply the algorithm `V-1` times once again to detect the Nodes in a negative cycle. This is `2 * O(VE) = O(VE)`.

I print a distances vector with the size `V` to display the distances and/or wether the node is in a negative cycle or not. `O(V)`.

So I guess my total complexity would be `O(VE + V + E)`. Now my question is: Since VE is almost always bigger than V+E (for large numbers, it's always!), can I drop the V+E in the complexity and make it simply `O(VE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `O(VE + V + E)` simplifies to `O(VE)` given that V and E represent the number of vertices and edges in a graph.  For a highly connected graph, `E = O(V^2)` and so in that case `VE + V + E = O(V^3) = O(VE)`.  For a sparse graph, `E = O(V)` (note, this is not necessarily a tight upper bound) and so `VE + V + E = O(V^2) = O(VE)`.  In all cases `O(VE)` is an appropriate upper bound on the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when dealing with asymptotic complexity, you always assume that `V` and `E` are very large (in theory, you study [complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) by calculating limits when `V` and `E` approach infinity). Pretty much the same why you can write `n^2 + n = O(n^2)`, in your case `VE + V + E` is `O(VE)`.

Note that the worst-case complexity of [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) actually is `O(VE)`, which confirms that your reasoning is correct.